# Clean logging of response from apache HttpClient (without 15:44:59.689 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 <<)

Tags: http, logging, httpclient, logback, apache-httpclient-4.x

I managed to turn on full debug logging on HttpClient. (using logback) I does log everything indeed but adds a lot of garbage headers on every line. I would like to have logging without any extra formatting, semicolons, quotes, encodings like this:

```
15:44:59.689 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "  <readOnly>false</readOnly>[\n]"
15:44:59.689 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "  <enabled>false</enabled>[\n]"
15:44:59.689 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "  <metadata>[\n]"
15:44:59.689 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "    <name>P[0xc5][0x99]ipoji[0xc5][0xa1]t[0xc4][0x9b]n[0xc3][0xad] denn[0xc3][0xad] d[0xc3][0xa1]vky p[0xc5][0x99]i pobytu v nemocnici n[0xc3][0xa1]sledkem [0xc3][0xba]razu d[0xc3][0xad]t[0xc4][0x9b]te</name>[\n]"
```

Simply if there is valid xml logged in, I want to copy paste whole chunk of log file into my favorite xml editor and see that it is exactly same data as what what came on wire. Is there a way how to achieve this ? I'm fine with extending classes from apache.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the log lines that you're trying to modify are being generated by the `org.apache.http.impl.conn.LoggingSessionInputBuffer` class, which in turn calls into `org.apache.http.impl.conn.Wire` to log the incoming data to the wire log.

Unfortunately, that `Wire` class is including the less-than symbols and the quotes in the logged message, so the best you could do with logback would be to use a minimal pattern layout in your logback.xml like

```
<pattern>%m%n</pattern>
```

which should yield something like this:

```
 << "  <readOnly>false</readOnly>[\n]"
 << "  <enabled>false</enabled>[\n]"
 << "  <metadata>[\n]"
 << "    <name>P[0xc5][0x99]ipoji[0xc5][0xa1]t[0xc4][0x9b]n[0xc3][0xad] denn[0xc3][0xad] d[0xc3][0xa1]vky p[0xc5][0x99]i pobytu v nemocnici n[0xc3][0xa1]sledkem [0xc3][0xba]razu d[0xc3][0xad]t[0xc4][0x9b]te</name>[\n]"
```

Since that still gives you more than you would like, maybe an easier approach would be to write a little sed script to grab the quoted message and remove the bracketed newline characters at the end.

Comment: This is quite interesting solution, however I'm not familiar with sed, and fells like I would need to decode national characters too (P[0xc5][0x99]ipoji)

Answer (score 0):

You could use logback [replace](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#replace) in the pattern:

```
<pattern>%replace(%msg){'\[0x9\]', '  '}%n</pattern>
```

This removed the [0x9] characters and replaces them with spaces. 
This is not ideal, but at least allows to cleanup some noise and makes the log more readable.